# Track and print amount of times the while loop was used

Tags: java, while-loop

I am writing a little mini game on jgrasp. The game is prompting a user to guess a number between 1 and 50. Then the while loop checks the "if" statement and lets them know if they guessed "to high" or "to low" and prompts them to guess again. I cannot figure out how to keep track of the amount of guesses a user takes. Any tips?? I am a beginner programmer, thanks for your help everyone.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Harrison6c {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the land of Hyrule!");
        System.out.println("The land here is extremley dangerous");
        System.out.println("Looks like you could use a sword");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("I'll tell you what lets play a game");
        System.out.println("I have a number between 1 and 50");
        System.out.println("Can you guess what it is?");
        System.out.println("If you guess the number correctly");
        System.out.println("I will give you something pretty cool!");
        System.out.println();

        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * (51 - 1)) + 1;

        int guessInt;
        guessInt = 0;

        while (guessInt != rand) {
            System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
            guessInt = input.nextInt();
            guessInt++;

            if (guessInt > rand) {
                System.out.println("Guess lower");
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (guessInt < rand) {
                System.out.println("Guess higher");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("You got It!");
        System.out.println("As promised here is your reward");
        System.out.println("You've recieved the Kokiri Sword!");
        System.out.println("Remember this land is very dangerous");
        System.out.println("That sword you now yield shall protect you!");

        System.out.println("You took" + guessInt++ + "guessess");
    }
}
```

heres my output

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java Harrison6c
Welcome to the land of Hyrule!
The land here is extremley dangerous
Looks like you could use a sword

I'll tell you what lets play a game
I have a number between 1 and 50
Can you guess what it is?
If you guess the number correctly
I will give you something pretty cool!

Enter your guess: 50
Guess lower

Enter your guess: 30
Guess lower

Enter your guess: 20
Guess higher

Enter your guess: 25
Guess higher

Enter your guess: 24
Guess higher

Enter your guess: 27
Guess higher

Enter your guess: 28
Guess higher

Enter your guess: 29
You got It!
As promised here is your reward
You've recieved the Kokiri Sword!
Remember this land is very dangerous
That sword you now yield shall protect you!
You took30guessess

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: Increment a variable inside the loop.

Comment: i tried doing this and its printing out the wrong number I guess I should add my code for feedback give me one second please.

Comment: If you've written some code, please post it here and someone can perhaps help you out.

Comment: Best thing is to post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as described at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I understand that there is something wrong with my increment variable  but I just cannot figure it out

Comment: @CodyHarrison you don't need `guessInt++;` if you rely on user to guess the correct number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another variable to increment the count of guesses as -

```
int guessInt = 0;
int guesses = 0; // this would track the count of guesses

while( guessInt != rand) {
  System.out.print( "Enter your guess: " );
  guessInt = input.nextInt();
  guesses++;

  if(guessInt > rand) {
    System.out.println("Guess lower");
    System.out.println();
  }
  if(guessInt < rand) {
   System.out.println("Guess higher");
   System.out.println();
  }
}

....
System.out.println("You took" + guesses + "guessess");
...
```

*Note* - You can clean your code by avoiding these many `S.out`s and using `\n` effectively.

Comment: works like a charm now, I have never used the \n operator I have just started using java I'll have to research and understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Replace `Int` with `guessInt`

```
System.out.println("You took"+guessInt++ +"guessess");
```

Comment: I'm sorry that was an error on my end, I originally had guessInt there

Comment: heres the output after